# Opera не воспроизводит MP3

Tags: аудио, браузер, opera, webkit

Не воспроизводится mp3 в опере. Версия: 47.0.2631.55, ОС ubuntu 16.04.

(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

Подскажите в чём причина и как исправить. Спасибо